# How to concert date time to just date in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, business-intelligence

Hi I’m trying to extract the m-dd-yyyy from a date function like this 9/4/2020 0.00 I don’t want the time stamp just the date in tableau

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the date time in the dimension list and set the default format

Answer (score 0):

Could also do:

```
datetrunc('day',[date_field])
```